# PSQL group row_to_jjson outputs

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that has a join on three different tables. I am trying to return all rows from the join, but group them into different objects based on their original table. I'm then wanting to call psql's `row_to_json` function on this.

My function looks something like this:

```
select format($q$
        select results
        from (
            select json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as results from (
                select g.* as all_g,o.* as all_o,d.* as all_d from schema.table_1 g
                join schema.table_2 o on g.eid = o.ev_id
                join schema.table_3 d on g.eid = d.id
                where g.eid = any(%1$L)
                ) s
        ) m;
    $q$,
        evs
    ) into q;

    return query execute q;
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
[
 {
  "all_g": {
    "eid": 1,
    "name": "testing"
   },
  "all_o": {
   "ev_id": 25,
   "type": "type_name"
   },
  "all_d": {
   "id": 6
   }
  },
 {
  "all_g": {
    "eid": 2,
    "name": "testing_again"
   },
  "all_o": {
   "ev_id": 14,
   "type": "type_name_2"
   },
  "all_d": {
   "id": 75
   }
  }
]
```

When I run my code, the `g.* as all_g` does not work as expected. Is it possible to do what I am looking for? To embed my results from each table within an outer object?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the structure as follows:

```
select format($q$
        select results
        from (
            select json_agg(row_to_json(s)) as results from (
                select row_to_json(g.*) as all_g,row_to_json(o.*) as all_o,row_to_json(d.*) as all_d from schema.table_1 g
                join schema.table_2 o on g.eid = o.ev_id
                join schema.table_3 d on g.eid = d.id
                where g.eid = any(%1$L)
                ) s
        ) m;
    $q$,
        evs
    ) into q;

    return query execute q;
```